# обработка json данных, подуровни определенных элементов

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

Пытаюсь древовидно вывести данные в TableView, создавая для каждого узла отдельный список[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 {
"ID": "0",
"Name": "Все",
"Departments": [
{
  "ID": "88",
  "Name": "IT офис",
  "Employees": [
    {
      "ID": "888",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по проектам",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "79358",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по проектам",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "46488",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Руководитель проектов",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "ID": "989",
  "Name": "Авиа",
  "Departments": [
    {
      "ID": "3058",
      "Name": "Отдел 1",
      "Employees": [
        {
          "ID": "88388",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Авиационный техник авиационного и радиоэлектронного оборудования",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "39806",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Авиационный техник ГСМ",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2553",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Автомеханик",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8981",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер летательных аппаратов и двигателей",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "4527",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "3460",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер по сертификации",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "3992",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Авиационный техник",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "7635",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Авиационный техник летательных аппаратов и двигателей",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "3918",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Главный инженер",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "3991",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер авиационного и радиоэлектронного оборудования",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "4013",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Авиационный техник авиационного и радиоэлектронного оборудования",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "306",
      "Name": "Отдел 2",
      "Employees": [
        {
          "ID": "5101",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Механик",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8063",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Менеджер по работе с клиентами",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "1944",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Заместитель директора по летной работе",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2820",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Экономист",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "1910",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Заместитель директора по общим вопросам",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2652",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Командир парашютного звена",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "4175",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Директор",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2752",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Начальник штаба",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2766",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Бухгалтер",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2827",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Директор",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "7155",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Начальник штаба",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "3459",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Начальник инженерно-авиационной службы",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "2950",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Комендант",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "4645",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер ИАС",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "308",
      "Name": "Отдел 3",
      "Departments": [
        {
          "ID": "309",
          "Name": "Подотдел 1",
          "Employees": [
            {
              "ID": "8309",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Водитель",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "310",
          "Name": "Подотдел 2",
          "Employees": [
            {
              "ID": "6137",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Авиационный техник",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "7225",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Авиационный техник летательных аппаратов и двигателей",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "311",
          "Name": "Подотдел 3",
          "Employees": [
            {
              "ID": "3840",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "4091",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2813",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Врач",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2869",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2654",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Летчик-методист",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "6999",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "4178",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот-инструктор",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2868",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "3915",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Пилот",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "312",
          "Name": "Подотдел 4",
          "Employees": [
            {
              "ID": "8272",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Водитель",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "4047",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Сторож",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2816",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Сторож",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "6037",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Разнорабочий",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "5805",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Повар",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "4048",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Сторож",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "8573",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Сторож"
            },
            {
              "ID": "11172",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Водитель",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "3852",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Разнорабочий",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "7680",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Повар"
            },
            {
              "ID": "5452",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Сторож",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "3019",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Разнорабочий",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "3483",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Сторож",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "7684",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Кладовщик",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ID": "313",
          "Name": "Подотдел 5",
          "Employees": [
            {
              "ID": "2655",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Парашютист-инструктор",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "6252",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Парашютист-инструктор",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2817",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Уборщица",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "6253",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Парашютист-инструктор",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "2653",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "Парашютист-инструктор",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            },
            {
              "ID": "3672",
              "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
              "Title": "мастер по ремонту парашютно-десантной техники",
              "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
              "Phone": "+79991112222"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "314",
      "Name": "Отдел 4",
      "Employees": [
        {
          "ID": "8780",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Старший инструктор парашютно-десантной подготовки"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8947",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Заведующий складом"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8793",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инструктор парашютно-десантной подготовки"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8766",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Начальник штаба"
        },
        {
          "ID": "9701",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Бухгалтер",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8767",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инструктор парашютно-десантной подготовки"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8786",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Комендант аэродрома"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8784",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инструктор парашютно-десантной подготовки"
        },
        {
          "ID": "9301",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Уборщица"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8775",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер инженерно-авиационной службы"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8785",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Техник по радионавигации, радиолокации, связи"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8774",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Стрелок военизированной охраны"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8768",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Старший стрелок военизированной охраны"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8948",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Летчик-инструктор"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8773",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Стрелок военизированной охраны"
        },
        {
          "ID": "8776",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Командир отряда"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "315",
      "Name": "Отдел 5",
      "Employees": [
        {
          "ID": "3458",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Инженер отдела технического контроля",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "5901",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "Заместитель директора по авиационной безопасности",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        },
        {
          "ID": "5811",
          "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
          "Title": "инженер-инспектор по безопасности полетов",
          "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
          "Phone": "+79991112222"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "ID": "328",
  "Name": "Тест 1"
},
{
  "ID": "254",
  "Name": "გამოძახება"
},
{
  "ID": "35",
  "Name": "Тест 3",
  "Employees": [
    {
      "ID": "4650",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Руководитель офиса",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "4651",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по работе с клиентами",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "9215",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по работе с клиентами",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "7079",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по работе с клиентами",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "10217",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по работе с клиентами",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    },
    {
      "ID": "4652",
      "Name": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
      "Title": "Менеджер по работе с клиентами",
      "Email": "test@yandex.ru",
      "Phone": "+79991112222"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "ID": "716",
  "Name": "გამოძახება"
}
  ]
}
```

Первый список, что показан на скриншоте создал так:

```
 NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                                                      if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseDic])
                                                      {
                                                          NSArray *array = responseDic[@"Departments"];
                                                          _tempDepart = [NSMutableArray new];
                                                          [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                                              [_tempDepart addObject:obj];
                                                          }];
                                                      }
```

А вот создавать списки дальше, возникли трудности :(
При нажатии на ячейку обновляю данные TableView, а в обновленном должно показывать уже подэлементы конкретной ячейки
Вот моя попытка, но для NSDictionary нельзя обратится по индексу, чтобы искать подэлементы у конкретного элемента:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
// Нажатие по ячейки
 _levelIndex++; // как глубого прошли внутрь
[_rememberStory addObject:[_tempDepart[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"]]; // создание истории, по которым шли вглубь
NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSArray *departments = responseDic[@"Departments"]; // создание списка 2 уровня
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseDic])
{
    NSArray *array = [departments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // для NSDictionary нельзя обратится по индексу
    NSLog(@"array:%@", array);
    NSLog(@"array count:%lu", (unsigned long)array.count);
    _tempDepart = [NSMutableArray new];
    [_tempDepart removeAllObjects];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { // падает программа
        [_tempDepart addObject:obj];
    }];
}

ViewControllerTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTable"];
detail.tempDepart = _tempDepart;
detail.tableViewData = _tableViewData;
detail.rememberStory = _rememberStory;
[self presentViewController:detail animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Объявление в .h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tempDepart;
```

Что касается цикла, как я понял, нельзя обратится к элементу:

```
NSArray *testArray = array[0]; // программа падает
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понял логику, почему первый раз Вы создаете массив, а второй раз словарик? Создайте во второй раз опять же массив

Comment: @VitaliEller
Внес изменения, программа падает в цикле. В цикл передается array, у которого есть три элемента сотрудников(показано на скриншоте) [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj пробовал тип obj заменить на NSArray, программа также падает в этом цикле, не доходя до добавления элементов

Comment: Какая ошибка при крэше?

Comment: @VitaliEller не может обратится по индексу

Comment: Похоже что у вас ячеек больше чем элементов в массиве, сколько у вас ячеек в таблице?

Comment: @VitaliEller -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _tempDepart.count;
}

Ячеек столько, сколько элементов в _tempDepart, но до вывода ведь еще не дошли...
p.s. речь о цикле, что при нажатии на ячейку

Comment: Приняли ответ, разобрались значит?

Comment: @VitaliEller с этим циклом да, благодарю за внимание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя поле @"Departments"] содержит массив, а ты пробуешь взять его как словарь.

Исправь это `NSDictionary *zeroResponeDic = responseDic[@"Departments"]; // создание списка 2 уровня`

на это `NSArray *departments = responseDic[@"Departments"]; // создание списка 2 уровня`

Каждый департамент представляет из себя словарь. Обращаться можно так:

```
NSDictionary *department = departments[ indexpath.row ];
```

`NSLog( @"name %@", department["Name"]);`

PS: на сайте http://json.parser.online.fr/ очень хорошо видно структуру json-а

Comment: Из такого словарика я смогу в будущем взять еще следующий "подсловарик"? Иными словами, NSLog( @"name %@", department["Name"]); содержит название офисов, а среди этих офисов могут быть еще подразделы или сотрудники, 
Смогу ли например из department[3] создать следующий подсловарик? Или может смогу обратится department[3][0]
p.s. извиняюсь за глупые вопросы

Comment: Да, ты сможешь взять любое поле и работать с ним. Будь то подмассив, число или подсловарик

Comment: В цикле программа падает
в цикл передается array, у которого есть три элемента сотрудников(показано на скриншоте)
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj пробовал тип obj заменить на NSArray, программа также падает в этом цикле, не доходя до добавления элементов

Comment: Выводи в лог каждый объект перед его использованием. Ты где-то с типами напутал

Comment: NSLog(@"Array%@", array[0]); при такой попытки вывода тоже падает, скриншот вывода array без индекса - обновил, также на скриншоте array.count = 3

Comment: У тебя вместо массива попался NSDict. Я ж говорю, выводи обьект, а не работай с ним сразу. [0] это уже работа. Тебя в этом словаре нужно взять поле Emploees, это должен быть массив. Посмотри на структуру на своем же скриншоте